# Cron job on Appengine - first time on start?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I am successfully running a cron job every hour on Google Appengine. However I would like it to start when I launch the app. Now it does the first cron job 1 hour after the start.

I am using Python.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "launch" the app in production as such.  You deploy the app for the first time and crontab is now present and crontab scheduling is started. So I assume you really mean you would like to run the cron job every time you deploy a new version of your application in addition to the cron schedule.

The cron handler is callable by you, so why not just wrap appcfg in a script that calls the cron handler after you do the deploy. Use wget/curl etc.....